# Which Jatakas illustrate Viriya Paramita

Tags: reference-request, bodhisattva, bodhisattva-vows

As far as I know, the story of Khantivadi illustrates the perfection of Khanti by the Bodhisatta, and the Vessantara Jataka illustrates the perfection of Dana - on similar lines - is there a Jataka(s) which illustrates the perfection of Viriya in the Pali Canon ? 
Also , Could anyone point out references to other articles/suttas/commentaries etc. inside/outside the Pali Canon on the topic of Viriya Paramita and its cultivation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commentary cites the Maha-Janaka Jataka (539) as the pinnacle of the perfection of effort:

> So I will ever do my best to fight through ocean to the shore;
>
> While strength holds out I still will strive, nor yield till I can strive no more."
>
> (Cowell, trans)

Also, the Vaṇṇupatha Jataka (#2) deals with this perfection. There's also one about a bird trying to put out a forest fire that comes to mind, but can't find it right now.